# How to get week date (7days interval) from SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table `tbl_Customer_Reg` and columns are

```
| ID   | Cust_Name | Registration_Date
+------+-----------+------------------
| 1001 | Mr. ABC   | 2021-03-13
| 1002 | Mr. MNO   | 2021-02-03
| 1003 | Mr. QWE   | 2021-04-12
| 1004 | Mr. XYZ   | 2021-01-17
```

Customers are subscribed to a weekly plan. That means every week they get a message and renew every week according to `Registration_Date`. That means Mr. XYZ renew every week 17,24,31 January 2021 and so on.

Now I want to know the current date (2021-08-20) or before what is the week date of Mr. XYZ.

Comment: Please include your expected results and the query you have so far that you are having problems with.

Comment: Do you want to know only the most recent renewal date, or all renewal dates since signup?

Comment: @Charlieface, yes want most recent renewal date and nextrenewal date accordingly. Most recent Renewal date is upto current date. And nextrenewal date is from tomorrow to next weeks.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should create table-function (use cross apply in query) which used cursor or CTE or while.
I write a simple with CTE(maxrecursion 200). You can try this:

```
CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION dbo.fnGetWeeklyDateWithDate(@date date)
RETURNS @Result TABLE(WeekDate date, Lev int)
AS 
begin
;WITH CTE 
AS
(
    SELECT @date WeekDate, 1 Lev
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD( Week, 1, WeekDate), Lev + 1
    FROM CTE c
    WHERE DATEADD( Week, 1, WeekDate) <= CAST(GETDATE() as date)
    AND Lev < 200
)
INSERT INTO @Result
SELECT WeekDate, Lev
FROM CTE
OPTION (maxrecursion 200)

RETURN 
END
```

result: 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

A little bit of date arithmetic should do the trick:

```
SELECT *,
  LastRenewal = DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, GETDATE(), Registration_Date) % 7, CAST(GETDATE() AS date)),
  NextRenewal = DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, GETDATE(), Registration_Date) % 7 + 7, CAST(GETDATE() AS date))
FROM YourTable;
```